# Short way to set or add numeric value of associative array?

Tags: php

Is there a shorter way to accomplish the following?

```
<?php
    $arr = [];

    // ...

    if(isset($arr['key']))
        $arr['key'] += 10;
    else
        $arr['key'] = 10;
?>
```

Comment: `$arr['key'] = ($arr['key'] ?? 0) + 10`? What have you tried?

Comment: @CodeCaster This gives me a syntax error

Comment: Is `@$arr['key'] += 10;` bad style in any way? Seems to be the shortest solution to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ternary operator:Try it

```
<?php
$arr = [];
// ...
$arr['key']= isset($arr['key'])?($arr['key']+10):10;
```

Comment: Clearly works, but I am still looking for a shorter version, if there is any available. Like with `if`, I still have to write `$arr['key']` thrice

Comment: Won't get shorter than ternary operator unless you want to @ suppress errors, which really isn't good practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
@$arr['key'] += 10;
```

seems to be the shortest solution.

Anything to say against it? Really not sure, whether `@` leads to inefficiencies

Comment: Yes, it is too short but new thing for me. Thank you @iceFire

Comment: The @ operator can defeat certain optimisations in the engine, because it basically has to add an instruction before your line to suppress the normal error handler, and one after to turn it back on again. As code gets more complex, you can also inadvertently suppress additional warnings which you want to see.

Comment: Inefficiencies is one thing, problems down the line is another. Do keep it compact, but don't sacrifice your code quality for brevity.

Comment: Added in a benchmark for the @-approach into my answer. So to answer the question, it does lead to inefficiencies, which may or may not be significant depending on your scale.

Answer (score 1):

You have several solutions:

## Function with reference

> Use `&` on the parameters
>
> This imply a new call of the function for each variable. Not good for resources, only for coding style :)

```
<?php

function addOrDefine(&$variable, $value, $defaultValue = null) {
    if( !isset($variable) )
        $variable = $defaultValue;
    $variable += $value;

    return $variable;
}

$varA = addOrDefine($array['toto'], 10);
$varA = addOrDefine($array['toto'], 10);

var_dump($varA); // output '20'

?>
```

You can create a define function:

```
<?php
function variableDefine(&$variable, $defaultValue = null) {
    if( !isset($variable) )
        $variable = $defaultValue;
    return $variable;
}
$varA = variableDefine($varA);
$varB = variableDefine($_GET['varB'], 'defaultvalue');
?>
```

## Another solution: simplify your syntax

```
<?php

if( !isset($array['toto']) ) {
  $array['toto'] = null;
}

$array['toto'] += 10;

?>
```

Can be simplified on:

```
<?php

if( !isset($array['toto']) )
  $array['toto'] = null;

$array['toto'] += 10;

?>
```

Or:

```
<?php

if( !isset($array['toto']) ) $array['toto'] = null;

$array['toto'] += 10;

?>
```

Assign value if the variable does not exists with default value. After, use the variable as usual.

## Ternary Operator

```
<?php

$varA = isset($array['toto']) ? $array['toto'] : 10;

// or
// if you want to use the previous point
$array['toto'] = isset($array['toto']) ? $array['toto'] : null;
$array['toto'] += 10;

?>
```

`$varA` is the value of the variable needed, with default value if it's not existing.

Comment: Last one ie. ternary operator is the shortest solution. #1 would incur a function call at each variable assignment. #2 brackets please. #3 what exactly is `$varA` supposed to do?

Comment: #1. Yes, but could be a good solution to initialize default values with a pretty style coding ... of course, this imply new function call & resources. #2. Why ? It's a way to simplify code (when we know what we do, of course :p). I added some examples with or without brackets.

Comment: #1: I'd use sparingly. #2: Omitting brackets doesn't really simplify the code. It just makes it two characters' worth shorter, and a lot harder to decipher if there are lots of them, or e.g. nested if/else conditions, especially when people don't indent their code properly. Makes your code more error-prone when the scope of the condition is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP7, you can take advantage of the new `??` [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). ("...*returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand*.")

```
$arr['key'] = ($arr['key'] ?? 0) + 10;
```

What happens above: The expression in the brackets sets `$arr['key']` to 0 if it isn't defined, otherwise leaves it as-is; and +10 is added to the result. This is the shortest approach.

---

The most common and easy-to-understand solution is using the `? :` ternary operator:

```
$arr['key'] = isset($arr['key']) ? $arr['key'] + 10 : 10; // or:
$arr['key'] = !isset($arr['key']) ? 10 : $arr['key'] + 10;
```

---

You could also do something like this:

```
isset($arr['key']) && ($arr['key'] += 10) || ($arr['key'] = 10);  // or:   
!isset($arr['key']) && ($arr['key'] = 10) || ($arr['key'] += 10);
```

---

Bottom line: There's no built-in solution in PHP for "define-if-not-exists", there will be a warning if you attempt to increment a non-existing variable.

*As far as some other answers here:* I wouldn't use @ to suppress errors, not good practice. Keep it short, not hackish. Incurring a separate function call on each variable increment seems excessive.

---

For those about to micro-optimize, and for the inquiring minds who need to know; benchmarks for 10M iterations of each. When defined once and then incremented in a loop; *Ex.1*: 2.43 sec; *Ex.2a*: 2.93 sec; *Ex.2b*: 3.03 sec, *Ex.3a*: 3.12 sec, *Ex.3b*: 3.02 sec. ... When unset & defined in each iteration; *Ex.1*: 3.49 sec, *Ex.2a*: 3.22 sec, *Ex.2b*: 3.86 sec, *Ex.3a*: 3.78 sec, *Ex.3b*: 4.50sec. (For context, simply defining the variable 10M times takes 1.85 sec, and unset+redefine takes 2.67 sec.)

Null-coalescing and ternary operators will perform better due to checking the variable directly in C instead of incurring a PHP isset function call. The error-suppressing `@$arr['key'] += 10;` approach clocks 2.39 sec in the first test; but clocks a heavy penalty in the second when the error suppression is triggered each time; 8.34 sec; and a whopping 53.7 sec if I leave my framework's error handler on!

Comment: Your first code snippet is not readable and has no advantage against `if(!isset($arr['key'])) $arr['key'] = 0;` Your second solution is my favorite. It has been posted similarly before, though, which is why I give the mark to them. Thank you, still!

Comment: Cheers @IceFire. The first example is perhaps not readable because you may not have encountered this usage/style of `&&` before? Is a very convenient shorty for ensuring a variable is set, and if not, gets set to a default. (Alongside the new `??` null coalescing operator; http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) But yeah, in this case a standard ternary is the clearest way to go.

Comment: I can read it but it has no advantage that I see and is more obscure which is why I do not like it.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't really add much, I've edited it out. The last example using the same logic is about as long and more usable. I've added in a `??` null coalescing operator example (that @CodeCaster suggested in an earlier comment). If you're on PHP7, that's the shortest way to do this.

Comment: Really the only merit in `!isset($arr['key']) && ($arr['key'] = 0)` for setting a default value is avoiding a "if-exists-then-define-as-itself" redundancy, which obviously has next-to-none impact on performance. (That said, it does satisfy some obscure corner of my brain.)